# How to pass JSON attributes as parameter to other Activity

Tags: android, json, listview

this is my code which shows JSON attributes in List View. I show only "name" in List View that I want to pass other attributes as parameter to other Activity. Below is my code
I just want to show only names "Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday" in List View. When user clicks other values like "dish, Gender, age" pass to other a Activity as parameter. How can do I do that?

```
{
"student": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Monday",
        "dish": "Biryani",
        "Gender": "M",
        "age": 10,
        "birthdate": "23/05/2002"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Tuesday",
        "dish": "Sandwish",
        "Gender": "M",
        "age": 12,
        "birthdate": "08/01/2000"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Wednesday",
        "dish": "Chicken Tikka",
        "Gender": "F",
        "age": 14,
        "birthdate": "01/03/1998"
    },





public class SeletecDayofweek extends Activity implements   
   OnItemClickListener {

private static final String rssFeed = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhk01nqlyj5gixl 
   /jsonparsing.txt?dl=1";

private static final String ARRAY_NAME = "student";
private static final String ID = "id";
private static final String NAME = "name";
private static final String CITY = "dish";
private static final String GENDER = "Gender";
private static final String AGE = "age";
private static final String BIRTH_DATE = "birthdate";


   ListView listMainMenu;
    List<Item> arrayOfList;
//MainMenuAdapter mma;
NewsRowAdapter objAdapter;
String myname;
JSONObject objJson ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.selectdayofweek);

    listMainMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMainMenu2);
    listMainMenu.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    arrayOfList = new ArrayList<Item>();

     if (URLUtils.isNetworkAvailable(SeletecDayofweek.this)) {
        new MyTask().execute(rssFeed);
    } else {
        showToast("No Network Connection!!!");
    }

}

// My AsyncTask start...

class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SeletecDayofweek.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return URLUtils.getJSONString(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (null != pDialog && pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (null == result || result.length() == 0) {
            showToast("No data found from web!!!");
            SeletecDayofweek.this.finish();
        } else {

            try {
                JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jsonArray = 
            mainJson.getJSONArray(ARRAY_NAME);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                     objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Item objItem = new Item();

                    objItem.setId(objJson.getInt(ID));
                    objItem.setName(objJson.getString(NAME));
                    myname= objJson.getString(NAME);
                    objItem.setCity(objJson.getString(CITY));

  objItem.setGender(objJson.getString(GENDER));
                    objItem.setAge(objJson.getInt(AGE));

        objItem.setBirthdate(objJson.getString(BIRTH_DATE));

                    arrayOfList.add(objItem);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            setAdapterToListview();

        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {



}


public void setAdapterToListview() {
    objAdapter = new NewsRowAdapter(SeletecDayofweek.this,   
   R.layout.main_menu_item,
            arrayOfList);
    listMainMenu.setAdapter(objAdapter);
}

public void showToast(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(SeletecDayofweek.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

  }






                             public class NewsRowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

private Activity activity;
private List<Item> items;
private Item objBean;
private int row;
Context context;

public NewsRowAdapter(Activity act, int resource, List<Item> arrayList) {
    super(act, resource, arrayList);
    this.activity = act;
    this.row = resource;
    this.items = arrayList;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    if ((items == null) || ((position + 1) > items.size()))
        return view;

    objBean = items.get(position);

    holder.tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtText);


    if (holder.tvName != null && null != objBean.getName()
            && objBean.getName().trim().length() > 0) {
        holder.tvName.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getName()));


    }


    return view;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvName, tvCity, tvBDate, tvGender, tvAge;
}
 }




                   public class Item {
private int id;
private String name;
private String city;
private String gender;
private int age;
private String birthdate;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getBirthdate() {
    return birthdate;
}

public void setBirthdate(String birthdate) {
    this.birthdate = birthdate;
}
}
```

Comment: my code display"names attribute liie monday"tuesday wednewday oin listview but how do i pas is other values as parameter to other activity? like when user click on monday pas is other values"dish"gender" age toother activity hwo do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Create a separate class** having fields corresponding fields for individual student in the `JSON` by parsing it just once. When populating the list view you can display just the names by creating a custom adapter of this class and overriding the `toString()` function which returns just the name.
2. When you move to the next activity, just **pass the selected object to the next activity** based on the selected item from the list.

---

**PS:- This solution might take a bit of time to code, but it exploits the object-oriented nature of Java and it is technically sound**

---

**EDIT 1:**

In my example i have used a students class with different set of fields!

1) Create a custom class for your student objects.

**`StudentDataForAttendance.java`**:

```
package com.kaavay.attendanceapplication.data;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
public class StudentDataForAttendance implements
    Comparable<StudentDataForAttendance> {
private final String    rollno;
private final String    name;
private final String    uniqueST;
private String       attendance;

public StudentDataForAttendance(final String rollno, final String name,
        final String uniqueST, final String attendance) {
    super();
    this.rollno = rollno;
    this.name = name;
    this.uniqueST = uniqueST;
    this.attendance = attendance;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(final StudentDataForAttendance another) {
    final String rollno1 = getRollno().toUpperCase();
    final String rollno2 = another.getRollno().toUpperCase();
    // ascending order
    return rollno1.compareTo(rollno2);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object o) {
    final StudentDataForAttendance sdfa = (StudentDataForAttendance) o;
    if (sdfa.getUniqueST().equals(getUniqueST()))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

/**
 * @return the attendance
 */
public String getAttendance() {
    return attendance;
}

/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @return the rollno
 */
public String getRollno() {
    return rollno;
}

/**
 * @return the uniqueST
 */
public String getUniqueST() {
    return uniqueST;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return super.hashCode();
}

public void setAttendance(final String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    attendance = string;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "StudentDataForAttendance [name=" + name + "]";
}
}
```

2) In your activity create an `AsyncTask` wherein you parse your `JSON` file and inside a loop create objects of student and store it in a **static object array** of type `StudentDataForAttendance` defined in your activity.

3) While populating your list activity code something like this:

```
final StudentListAdapter studentAdapter = new StudentListAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.lvStudentAttendance,
            studentData);
    lvStudentAttendance.setAdapter(studentAdapter);
```

where `StudentListAdapter` is as below:

```
public class StudentListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private List<StudentDataForAttendance>  studentData = new ArrayList<StudentDataForAttendance>();
Context                                context;
int                                    listViewResourceId;

public StudentListAdapter(final Context context, final int resource,
        final int textViewResourceId,
        final StudentDataForAttendance[] studentData) {
    super();
    // Log.d("Constructor", "Run");
    this.studentData = Arrays.asList(studentData);
    this.context = context;
    listViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return studentData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(final int position) {
    return studentData.get(position).getName();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(final int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView,
        final ViewGroup parent) {
    //You can put any data to your rows of the list here is there is a need to
            //display more than just names in your case!!!! What i have used
            //is custom layout for each of the rows
    View v = null;
    // For reusing cells when out of view
    if (convertView == null) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_cell_student_list, parent,
                false);
    }
    else
        v = convertView;
    //
            //
    //What i have coded here is not important to your question
            //
            //
            //
            //
    return v;
}
}
```

This is the correct way of doing it!

---

***EDIT 2**:
For getting the object clicked what you do is in this method

```
public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> av, final View v,
        final int position, final long id)
```

get the object

```
final StudentDataForAttendance clickedStudent = studentData[position];
```

and use it to pass it to the next activity, where `studentData` is my **static object array** consisting of the objects from the `JSON`

Comment: how i do that give me any example

Comment: i did like this but is pass all values of selected postion to other activity how do i divide that??

Comment: if(!jsonArray.isNull(position)){
            Intent intent = new Intent(SeletecDayofweek.this,TodayLunch.class);  
            intent.putExtra("name", jsonArray.optJSONObject(position).toString());
            startActivity(intent);

Comment: @user2527915 in my code there is no need to use json once you have parsed it to create the objects... you just have to use the objects for any of your operations then!

Comment: no in my application so many json so imnot used same clas every where  what ever url user click diffrent json come so i ewan tto parse on that to other class

Comment: @user2527915 i didn't get what you actually mean by " parse on that to other class"

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent Extras as below:

When a listItem is clicked, get the listitem and store in a String and pass it to otherscreen as below:

```
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
    long id) {
      Intent i = new Intent(CurrentClass.this, TargetClass.class);
 i.putExtra("WEEK_DAY", ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listrow_id).getText().toString());
 i.putExtra("WEEK_DISH", dish_data);
 i.putExtra("AGE", age);
 startActivity(i);
 }
```

and get the data in other Activity as,

```
Intent  i= getIntent();
String week_day = i.getStringExtra("WEEK_DAY");
String week_dish = i.getStringExtra("WEEK_DISH");
String week_age = i.getStringExtra("AGE");
```

Comment: i know how to pass as parameter but what i write in right site of this 

i.putExtra("WEEK_DAY", ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listrow_id).getText().toString());
 i.putExtra("WEEK_DISH", here);
 i.putExtra("AGE", here);

Comment: tel me how to get out selected position attributes from json? supose user click on monday how do i pass only  monday attributes as parameter to other activity??

Comment: @user2527915 create 5 `TextViews` for `WEEK_DAY`, `WEEK_DISH`, `AGE`, `GENDER`, `BIRTHDATE` in `R.layout.main_menu_item` and set `android:visibility="gone"` for all the TextViews except `WEEK_DAY` and set `android:visibility="visible"` for `WEEK_DAY` and pass the parameters to another Activity using `Intent.putExtra();`